# Conversion of anonymous pattern matching functions

Tags: scala

I observe that Scala anonymous pattern matching functions behave magically, as shown by the following code:

```
trait MyFunction {
  def map(value: String): String
}
val f1: MyFunction = { case e: String => e.toLowerCase() }
val f: Function[String, String] = { case e: String => e.toLowerCase() }
val f2: MyFunction = f
val pf: PartialFunction[String, String] = { case e: String => e.toLowerCase() }
val f3: MyFunction = pf
```

The first assignment, from function to `MyFunction`, does compile. According to https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions, the type of anonymous pattern matching function is either `Function` or `PartialFunction`. However, when I first assign the expression to instance of `Function` or `PartialFunction`, and then assign to `MyFunction`, that does not compile, with

```
Expression of type Function[String, String] doesn't conform to expected type MyFunction
```

So my question is - what is the magic that makes assignment to `f1` compile? The behavior appear to be the same in 2.11, 2.12 and 2.13.

Comment: In 2.11 `f1` doesn't compile. https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types

Comment: Yes, you are both correct, directly compiling with 2.11 results in error; apparently my IDE uses 2.12 by default regardless of gradle settings.

Comment: And I presume that assigning one SAM class to another is not allowed?

Comment: Generally not allowed, it's a type mismatch, unless you define implicit conversion.